# Prevent editing appointments and tasks in outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-2010, mapi

Is it possible to prevent a user from editing appointments and tasks in Outlook. The tasks and appointments are synchronized using an addin we are developing.

We want to make a first release, but we have to prevent the user from editing the items, because we can't sync to changes at to moment back to the server.

We use Redemption to create the appointments and tasks, Which is build on MAPI.

We are also using AddinExpress to make some things happen in Outlook.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you create your own store provider, you cannot make a truly read-only appointment or task.
You can try to intercept the Wrire event on each particular item and set the Cancel parameter to true.